# Почему команда while работает в этом случае?

Tags: python

Код для решения задачки из ЕГЭ.

```
l = 0
m = 0
x = 126464
d = 0
while (m != 4) and (l != 13):
    x += 1
    d = x
    l = 0
    m = 0
    while d > 0:
        m += 1
        if d % 8 > 4:
            l = l + (d % 8)
        d = d // 8
    print(l)
    print(m)
print (x)
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте свой вопрос. На данный момент непонятно, в чём заключается проблема, и что вам непонятно.

Comment: А она почему-то должна не работать?

Comment: Программа должна завершить свою работу, когда переменная m будет равна 4, а L будет равна 13. При x = 126465 L = 13, а m = 6 и цикл все равно прекращает работу, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы неправильно записываете условие

> Программа должна завершить свою работу, когда переменная m будет равна
>   4, а L будет равна 13

должно быть :

```
while not ((m == 4) and (l == 13)):
```

или, что тоже самое

```
while (m != 4) or (l != 13):
```